# Magento 2 How to add custom product relations?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, related-products

I am needing to add another related products attribute to associate multiple other products.

I have found a solution for Magento 1: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-product-relations-in-magento/

However, I wishing to implement this in Magento 2. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Which is exactly your Magento version?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/magepal/link-product

Comment: @adamhs Does your requirement fulfilled?? even i am looking for the same thing. Can u plz help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Magento 2.0.x version:**

First of all, there are some notes:

--Replaced event `catalog_product_prepare_save` with controller product initialization helper that can be customized via plugins - `Vendor/ProductRelation/Model/Product/Initialization/Helper/ProductLinks.php`.

--Replaced event `catalog_model_product_duplicate` with composite `Product\Copier` model. However, we don't use this event.

--We need to override the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link\Proxy` - can find it under `var/generation`.

Now, let's start to build our module:

## Installer script

Create a setup script to add new product link type:

```
#app/code/Vendor/ProductRelation/Setup/UpgradeData.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductRelation\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Upgrades DB for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        //Add store_id to catalog_product_link
        $productLinkTable = 'catalog_product_link';
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                    $setup->getTable($productLinkTable),
                    'store_id',
                    [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'default' => 0,
                        'comment' => 'Store Id'
                    ]
            );


        /**
         * Install product link types
         */
        $data = [
            ['link_type_id' => \Vendor\ProductRelation\Model\Catalog\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_CUSTOMTYPE, 'code' => 'customtype']
        ];

        foreach ($data as $bind) {
            $setup->getConnection()
                ->insertForce($setup->getTable('catalog_product_link_type'), $bind);
        }

        /**
         * install product link attributes
         */
        $data = [
            [
                'link_type_id' => \Vendor\ProductRelation\Model\Catalog\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_CUSTOMTYPE,
                'product_link_attribute_code' => 'position',
                'data_type' => 'int',
            ]
        ];

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->insertMultiple($setup->getTable('catalog_product_link_attribute'), $data);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

## Admin interface

Add new tab to product information

```
#app/code/Vendor/ProductRelation/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_tabs">
            <block class="Vendor\ProductRelation\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab" name="product.customtype">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Type</argument>
                    <argument name="url" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/product/customtype">
                        <param name="_current">1</param>
                    </argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ajax</argument>
                    <argument name="group_code" xsi:type="string">advanced</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product-customtype</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">product.customtype</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In this layout, we need to define the url path `path="catalog/product/customtype"` to load the grid. We will create this controller later. - `Vendor/ProductRelation/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Customtype.php`

The block for rendering the tab.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductRelation\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit;

class Tab extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Creating the controllers:

--Get custom products grid and serializer block

```
#app/code/Vendor/ProductRelation/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Customtype.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductRelation\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;

class Customtype extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $resultLayoutFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder $productBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $productBuilder);
        $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get products grid and serializer block
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->productBuilder->build($this->getRequest());
        $resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
        $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.product.edit.tab.customtype')
            ->setProductsCustomtype($this->getRequest()->getPost('products_customtype', null));
        return $resultLayout;
    }
}
```

--Get custom products grid

```
#app/code/Vendor/ProductRelation/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/CustomtypeGrid.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductRelation\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;

class CustomtypeGrid extends Customtype
{

}
```

Create two layouts for two controllers above:

```
#app/code/Vendor/ProductRelation/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_customtype.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Vendor\ProductRelation\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Customtype"
               name="catalog.product.edit.tab.customtype"/>
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer" name="customtype_grid_serializer">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="input_names" xsi:type="string">position</argument>
                <argument name="grid_block" xsi:type="string">catalog.product.edit.tab.customtype</argument>
                <argument name="callback" xsi:type="string">getSelectedCustomtypeProducts</argument>
                <argument name="input_element_name" xsi:type="string">links[customtype]</argument>
                <argument name="reload_param_name" xsi:type="string">products_customtype</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</layout>


#app/code/Vendor/ProductRelation/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_customtypegrid.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Vendor\ProductRelation\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Customtype"
               name="catalog.product.edit.tab.customtype"/>
    </container>
</layout>
```

Get custom products grid block:

`app/code/Vendor/ProductRelation/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Customtype.php`

[Here.](https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_ProductRelation/blob/master/Boolfly/ProductRelation/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Customtype.php)

If continuing to post more code lines here, this topic is too long. So, I will focus on main ideas.

One of the most important things is `di.xml`

```
#app/code/Vendor/ProductRelation/etc/di.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product"
                type="Vendor\ProductRelation\Model\Product"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link"
                type="Vendor\ProductRelation\Model\Catalog\Product\Link"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link\Proxy"
                type="Vendor\ProductRelation\Model\Catalog\Product\Link\Proxy"/>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Initialization\Helper\ProductLinks">
        <plugin sortOrder="4" name="afterInitializeLinks"
                type="Vendor\ProductRelation\Model\Product\Initialization\Helper\ProductLinks"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

As we can, the same logic on Magento 1, we will override Product and Product Link model. However, we also need to override the Product Link Proxy and used Plugin to override `initializeLinks` method.

There is another note. We can reuse the admin catalog routes:

```
#app/code/Vendor/ProductRelation/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="catalog">
            <module name="Vendor_ProductRelation" before="Magento_Catalog" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Full source code for this extension is available from [GitHub repository page](https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_ProductRelation).

**Magento 2.1.x or later version**

I will update later on this page or Github.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had already started to try and implement my own module, however, I will be using yours to improve mine and finish it. I should mention that I am using Magento 2.1. I will update once I hopefully have it working.

Comment: Yeah! @adamhs you can contribute to my module on Github - I'm going to make my module works on Magento 2.1 version also.

Comment: Hi Khoa, I have the products table in the adminhtml and am able to select the products. I have also updated the schema to have the customtype link. However, I am stuck in getting the products to save to the database. When I click Save on the product page it is not being added to database.

Comment: You're working on 2.1 version?

Comment: Sorry should have mention. Yep 2.1

Comment: So, you used UI component for this module?

Comment: Correct. I have an extra section for customtype amongst the normal 3 - Customtype / Related / Crosssell / Upsell. Clicking the Customtype slides out the modal from the right.

Comment: To update. I have it working in Magento 2.1 - The implementation is a bit different. Im basically copying the core Magento build and so my CustomType sits in the same tab as the normal 3. Later I may be able to add to the repository page with a solution for Magento 2.1.
Thank you for your solution to Magento 2 @Khoa TruongDinh. It was a great help in working out 2.1

Comment: @adamhs How can i call Customtype section in separate tab rather than Related/crosssell/upsell product tab?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i have downloaded your module from github and its working on magento v2.2.2, but its not working on Magento2.2.4. can you please help me to suggest , In which files i need to work to resolve that issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh could you please provide me Magento 2.2.5 compatible module?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I installed this module and it is not even showing tabs in product edit page.

Comment: If any one can help in getting values of this in frontend inside product page?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Can i get github link if you have build this code for 2.3.2?