# Magento 2 : Copy "Related Product" functionality in custom module

Tags: magento2, product, extensions, related-products, product-relations

I just want to select some products on the edit page and show them on the product page. It should be the same function, as in Related Products, Up-sells, and Cross-Sells.

Can I simply copied some files for create a custom module? Or maybe someone know a suitable extension?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use the existing functionality of related, upsells, and cross-sell?

Comment: Magento1? or M2?

Comment: @RaulSanchez M2

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I need to link several products together. For example, I have a "Right Hand Chase" and "Left Hand Chase" sofas. I want that my cusomers will see them in the category as two different products and have a possibility to chose this configuration in a product page.

Comment: Here you have a good point to start https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137518/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-product-relations

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev are you able to find this type of functionality ?